# repeater page break after n items for printing

Tags: .net, html, css, printing, repeater

Printing a web page which has a list of items will sometimes result in the items getting garbled across the second page.

Is there a way to insert a css class definition after so many items have been inserted on a page?

The relevant css would be tied to the page break definition:

```
.page-break  { page-break-before: always; }
```

relevant page code for the repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="SearchResultsRepeater" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            [content]
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <li class="SystemShaded">
            [content]
        </li>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <li class='<%# (Container.ItemIndex + 1) % 10 == 0? "page-break" : "" %>'>
        <!-- [content]  -->
    </li>
</ItemTemplate>
```